# Replace text tokens with HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, token

What is the best way to look through an HTML element like a DIV and replace a specific piece of text with an HTML element.  For example assume we have the tokens `[b]` and `[/b]`.  I'd want to replace them with `<b>` and `</b>`, respectively.

The closest I have gotten this to work is the example below.

HTML to teplace:

```
<div id="response">This is some [b]GREAT[/b] stuff!</div>
```

---

Example #1:

```
$('#response').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace('[b]', '<b>');
});
$('#response').html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('[/b]', '</b>');
});
```

Result #1:

> This is some GREAT stuff!

---

Example #2:

```
$('#response').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace('[b]', $('<b>'));
});
$('#response').html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('[/b]', $('</b>'));
});
```

Result #2:

> This is some [object Object]GREAT[object Object] stuff!

---

Desired result:

> This is some **GREAT** stuff!

Neither works. The former simply replaces the token with nothing, and the latter replaces it with an object in the browser, but not the HTML element as desired.

Comment: do you want specifically a jQuery answer, or are you ok with a pure javascript one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a regular expression should do nicely:

```
$('#response').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\[(\/?\w+)\]/g, "<$1>");
});
```

The benefit is that *all* tokens are replaced without having to name them individually.

**Note that this opens the door for cross site scripting attacks!**

---

If you want to transform tokens in the process (like `[b]` to `<strong>`) and whitelist them (and you *definitely* want to whitelist them to migitate XSS vulnerability), use a callback function as the replacement, like this:

```
$('#response').html(function () {
    var map = {
        b: "strong",
        i: "em",
        p: "p"
    };
    return $(this).text().replace(/\[(\/?)(\w+)\]/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty($2)) {
            return "<" + $1 + map[$2] + ">";
        } else {
            return $0;
        }
    });
});
```

---

And to make this a jQuery answer, here's how to turn all that into a fancy jQuery plugin for re-use:

```
$.fn.extend({
    unphpbb: (function () {
        var map = {
               b: "strong",
               i: "em",
               p: "p"
            },
            tokens = /\[(\/?)(\w+)\]/g,
            replacement = function ($0, $1, $2) {
                return map.hasOwnProperty($2) ? "<" + $1 + map[$2] + ">" : $0;
            },
            replaceTokens = function (i, html) {
                return html.replace(tokens, replacement);
            };

        return function () {
            return this.html(replaceTokens);
        };
    })()
});
```

used as

```
$("#response").unphpbb();
```

---

Of course using a bbcode parser *on the server* and sending properly scrubbed HTML to the client is the preferred method for solving this. Doing this on the client with a function like above is inferior in every way.

Comment: This is elegant, but if OP needs only a strict set of tags to be parsed, and some of them have different output -- such as in PHPBB where `[*]` -> `<li>`, `[list]` -> `<ul>` etc. -- you would rather use a callback function and check against an object's keys to check if it is a valid token and get the correct tag replacement.

Comment: Both concerns tended to in my extended answer.

Comment: @Ginden it'd probably be good to avoid that :) Browsers won't pay attention to inline JavaScript in replacement HTML, but they do load scripts from remote URLs.

Comment: @Pointy I believe jQuery's `.html()` evaluates script tags (unlike the vanilla `.innerHTML`), this exploit was fixed in Tomalak's updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your first effort looks better but you should probably do it in one call so as not to produce broken HTML between calls, eg

```
$('#response').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace('[b]', '<b>').replace('[/b]', '</b>');
});
```

You could even try this regular expression replacement instead

```
var rx = /\[(\/?[a-z]+)\]/g;
return $(this).text().replace(rx, '<$1>');
```

The regex approach would also let you define a set of allowed tags (so as not to support things like `<script>`), eg

```
var rx = /\[(\/?(b|i|strong|em|u|tt))\]/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to parse what is essentially [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode). Patrick Gillespie [wrote this JS Library](https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser) that seems pretty simple to implement.

```
var result = XBBCODE.process({
    text: "Some bbcode to process here",
    removeMisalignedTags: false,
    addInLineBreaks: false
});
console.log("Errors: " + result.error);
console.dir(result.errorQueue);
console.log(result.html);// the HTML form of your BBCode
```